# Plotting histogram of vertical projection of an image

Tags: python, histogram

Looking for plotting a historgram in a vertical projection of an image

```
def verticalProjection(img):
   "Return a list containing the sum of the pixels in each column"
   (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
   sumCols = []
   for j in range(w):
       col = img[0:h, j:j+1] # y1:y2, x1:x2
       sumCols.append(np.sum(col))
   return sumCols
def slice_digits(image_name):
    img = cv2.imread(image_name, 0)
    img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
    y = verticalProjection(img)
    height_hist = np.histogram(y, bins=500)
    plt.hist(height_hist, bins=500, normed=True)

    plt.show()
    plt.plot(y)
```

I'm expecting a histogram that shows the various heights of an image. 
The image example is here:
[image]

That should show a different heights, but I don't get that result, what I'm doing wrong ?

That's what I get

[image]

Actually a correct histogram should show various characters with different height, but that doesn't seem to work with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.hist` already calculates the histogram. Because you are passing it the result of `numpy.histogram`, you are effectively plotting the histogram of the histogram's y-values.

Replace

```
plt.hist(height_hist, bins=500, normed=True)
```

with

```
plt.hist(y, bins=500, normed=True)
```